# Scala, PostgreSQL - how to create list of objects as jsonb[] in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, scala, quill

I have a simple postgres schema:

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
   name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   products jsonb[]
);
```

Now I created a mdoel in Scala to add array of jsons into database:

```
case class Product
(
   name: String,
   number: Int
)
case class Person
(
    name: String,
    products: Option[List[Product]]
)
```

But when I want to add it via Quill into database I got an error:

```
  InternalPersistenceError(Some(U0000000DN),Left(java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.github.jasync.sql.db.postgresql.exceptions.GenericDatabaseException: ErrorMessage(fields=[(Severity, ERROR), (V, ERROR), (SQLSTATE, 22P02), (Message, invalid input syntax for type json), (Detail, Token "Product" is invalid.), (Where, JSON data, line 1: Product...), (File, json.c), (Line, 22), (Routine, report_invalid_token)])))
```

It seems that json could not be saved into db, but I have no idea why? I'm using raw types everywhere, it looks straight forward. Maybe there is another possibility to save array of jsons into postgres via scala?

Comment: `jsonb[]` hardly ever make sense. Using `jsonb` as the column's type and storing a JSON array inside it is typically a much better solution.

Comment: I changed it to `jsonb` but still same error

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the following for the circe json version of the desired case class you want to insert:

```scala
  implicit val jsonEncoder: Encoder[Json] = encoder[Json](Types.OTHER,
    (index: Index, json: Json, row: PrepareRow) => {
      val pgObj = new PGobject()
      pgObj.setType("jsonb")
      pgObj.setValue(json.noSpaces)
      row.setObject(index, pgObj, Types.OTHER)
    }
  )
  implicit val jsonDecoder: MappedEncoding[String, Json] = MappedEncoding[String, Json](str => {
    io.circe.parser.parse(str) match
      case Right(v) => v
      case Left(err) => throw new SQLException(s"Could not parse string to error", err)
  })
```